# Command prompt hangs until keypress?

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line, terminal

**Problem:**

For some reason once in a while my command prompt would hang until I press a random key, and it would continue operation as if nothing happened.

**Occurrence:**

This happens when I am running a long operation (such as building/compiling some code). When it hangs, it gives no indication of what's going on nor does it prompt me to press any key.

**Description:**

1. After a couple minutes, the terminal stops printing out the progress, and gets stuck.
2. I had thought that it was simply stuck on a very lengthy portion of the compile process, but after a few hours it was still stuck on the exact same place.
3. I pressed a random key, and it suddenly jumped straight back and continued spewing out progress indicators and continued working.

After this, similar events have happened many times during lengthy processes, such as copying files.

This has happened on multiple devices running windows 7. It has also occurred on Ubuntu using bash shell.

Comment: Any of these machines set to sleep at all?

Comment: No, the machine doesn't go to sleep, just the terminal apparently. The machines also don't have sleep or any low power modes enabled. And have never once gone into sleep mode in their entire life time (Since I bought/built them)

Comment: It sounds like you're having the same issue from two completely different environments (Linux and Windows). So you might ask what do these two things have in common? Is it the same script/code? Copying to the same server?

Comment: This has happened many times over several years on completely different tasks. Some things Ive done that I remember: making a build at work, copying some files locally (robocopy on windows and cp on linux), rsync on remote servers, running batch scripts, etc

Comment: Those who are wondering if it is still an issue,Yes !

Comment: Still a problem in 2020

Comment: I think this is going to become one of humanity's greatest unsolved mysteries

Comment: Same problem in 2021. Windows 10 Home, 20H2. Does anyone have a work around?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prevent sleep in scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/90415/prevent-sleep-in-scripts)

Comment: Most of the time it's because mark mode has been enabled and you accidentally clicked inside the console: [Command prompt gets stuck and continues on enter key press](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13599822/995714)

Comment: Still a problem in 2022!

Comment: @Bakhshi not at all if you use the new Windows Terminal, or disable quickedit in the old terminal

Comment: Still a problem in 2023! but the disable quickedit hack kind of fixed it. The problem still comes and goes but it's less predominant.

Answer (score 40):

I have experienced the same issue.
Answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591047/command-line-windows-hanging-in-rdp-windows) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/314194/why-does-windows-command-prompt-stalls-until-a-key-is-pressed-when-executing-lon) indicate this is likely an issue with Quick Edit mode in the console.  If it intercepts stray mouse clicks, or if clicks get passed erroneously through RDP, for instance, it can unintentionally pause the script.  You can right-click the menubar and edit properties to turn off Quick Edit mode.  That, of course, makes it more difficult to copy and paste out of the CMD window.

Comment: I have quick edit mode off, and experience this often in node. No issues on linux. But windows will  seem to pause, until I ctr C once. This continues the node process. Seems like it would kill the process if it was truly hanging.

Comment: I have disabled quick edit mode so will keep an eye. My solution is to resize my cmd prompt, or power shell window a bit - to get the npm script to continue. Very strange indeed.

Comment: I've seen this for 20 years in windows. It has appeared and disappeared many times... I think its Microsoft not doing proper regression testing, because it comes and goes every few years

Comment: Experiencing this regularly these days when running python3.7 scripts in powershell, very annoying :(

Answer (score 5):

The old Windows console has a separate mode called "mark mode" for selecting text. In that mode the screen will be frozen for ease of selection

[image: Mark mode]

If QuickEdit mode is enabled (by default it's [disabled in older Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070913-00/?p=25143) but [enabled in Windows 10](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/take-a-look-at-windows-10s-new-command-prompt-features/)) then clicking inside the console window will activate mark mode and result in what you observed

It's very easy to accidentally click the console and stop the command. When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> the selected text will be copied to clipboard and mark mode will be exited, therefore the process will run again

Here's an example of QuickEdit mode setting in Windows 8 console:

[image: cmd]

To fix this you can **disable QuickEdit** mode if you don't need it. In this case copying will be more troublesome because you must open the context menu, select *Edit > Mark*. You can also disable QuickEdit mode by setting `ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE` with [`SetConsoleMode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) if you're writing your own console application

But the better solution is to **use [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal)** which is significantly better, faster, more featureful and more powerful

## See also

- [How and why does QuickEdit mode in Command Prompt freeze applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30418886/995714)
- [What does it do exactly if I click in the window of cmd?](https://superuser.com/q/459609/241386)
- [Windows command prompt freezing on focus](https://superuser.com/q/555160/241386)
- [Why does Windows command prompt stalls until a key is pressed when executing long batch files or programs](https://serverfault.com/q/314194)
- [Turn off Windows 10 console "Mark" mode from my application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41409727/995714)

Answer (score -1):

I found this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/90415/prevent-sleep-in-scripts), and it works for me on Windows 10 20H2. The trick seems to be,

```
powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 0
```

Comment: If you found a question, with an answer that answers this question, you should flag it as a duplicate. We try to avoid answers that just point to another answer.

Comment: Until someone flags the question as a duplicate, it's still good to have an answer here. It's a 10 year old question with 40k views and otherwise no clear answer so far. The downvotes on a potential solution make no sense for someone coming from Google.