# Windows command prompt freezing on focus

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a few python scripts which contain no pause commands and no prompts for user input however I find that when I change my window focus to the Windows cmd window the output will freeze until I press 'Enter'.

Is there a know cause for this? Should I enable/disable a setting in the cmd options to avoid this?

A search of my case keeps bringing up cases of people wanting pauses in their code - which I do not.

Comment: BTW, you can vote on UserVoice to get this behavior changed: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/31941592-selecting-text-shouldn-t-pause-program

Answer (score 43, accepted):

How are you selecting/focussing that window? If you simply <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to it or click its titlebar, the scrolling output shouldn't pause. My guess is you have **QuickEdit Mode** turned on (right-click the command prompt windows's titlebar and select **Properties**) and you are clicking *inside* the window with your mouse, thus selecting text by mistake and causing the program to pause.

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks Karan. Yes I was using QuickEdit to select some text from the output of my scripts. Disabling this gets around the pausing. Shame the cmd window can't let you select text without pausing the output.

Comment: Don't you think it would be difficult to select text that's quickly scrolling off the screen?

Comment: I guess it depends on how "quickly" it is scrolling off the screen.

Comment: The reasoning to make it freeze is likely dictated by some old software limitation(s), not because it's convenient for the user. Modern apps would have its process continue down below the selection and show a scrollbar.

Comment: And it's awesome that Windows doesn't provide an easy way to prevent an individual batch script's cmd from having this option enabled without doing something 'hacky'...it's kind of silly how Windows presents you the options of trusting the end user to disable this option in their cmd, doing something 'hacky', or implementing your own GUI to send stdout/err to in order to display without this issue.

Comment: You must DESELECT this two options!

Comment: In the MS feedback hub app you can find and upvote (or create a new request if you don't) with the title: `When the console is paused, display a  warning sign: "command paused"`