# Do programs run from the command prompt really pause while selecting text from the cmd window in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

I was working with a vendor today and they ran their executable from a `cmd` window, where it logged and logged in whatever passes for real-time in Windows...in my experience with things like this on windows you have to flush the buffer to get accurate logs "as they happen" (well in IE anyway), this was just writing output to the cmd shell, not to a file.

We were testing things and then copying the logs created by them to a text file from the window.

At one point we couldn't use the program because the vendor still had text selected in the cmd window...he copied the text out of the window and stated that if you run a program like that it freezes the application until after you copy the text from the cmd shell.

Is that true?  And if so, why?  I'm not sure if it's maybe something node.js specific on Windows, but I've never heard that before.

Comment: The answer is "it depends", and it depends on many factors. If you are trying to figure out how to avoid this, you can create outside processes that handle the input and output.

Comment: *Is that true?* Yes. When you copy-paste from/to CMD window the execution is suspended on the stage of output into this CMD window (its output buffer). But when the process output nothing in this time its execution is not suspended (until the attempt to output something). *And if so, why?* Output may alter current window text (in the place where it is currently selected, for example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows command prompt freezing on focus](https://superuser.com/questions/555160/windows-command-prompt-freezing-on-focus)