# Temporarily change energy settings without having to change my power plan in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, energy

I'm not particularly fond of windows 7's energy management features.

I think it's really cumbersome as I seem to have to change the current plan to do anything. And sometimes I don't want to change the plan - sometimes I just want to instruct the computer to do everything it's doing, just not automatically sleep cause I'm downloading something.

But it seems every time I want to do this, I am made to go through a number of different screens and options and then I have to remember to reset it back afterwards.

Is there a way to just temporarily override the options within my plan, with options like Do Not Sleep button? Or "Instantly Turn Off Monitor" button or "Don't go to sleep when I turn off lid" button?

Comment: Related: [prevent sleep in scripts](//superuser.com/q/90415)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a free program called Insomnia that will keep a computer awake as long as it's running.

http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9901642

---

Since the link has already changed once, here is the important part of the program source taken from the link above so that it can be reproduced if the link ever goes down permanently.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private uint m_previousExecutionState;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set new state to prevent system sleep (note: still allows screen saver)
        m_previousExecutionState = NativeMethods.SetThreadExecutionState(
            NativeMethods.ES_CONTINUOUS | NativeMethods.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);
        if (0 == m_previousExecutionState)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Call to SetThreadExecutionState failed unexpectedly.",
                Title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            // No way to recover; fail gracefully
            Close();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);

        // Restore previous state
        if (0 == NativeMethods.SetThreadExecutionState(m_previousExecutionState))
        {
            // No way to recover; already exiting
        }
    }

    private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        // Start an instance of the NavigateUri (in a browser window)
        Process.Start(((Hyperlink)sender).NavigateUri.ToString());
    }
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    // Import SetThreadExecutionState Win32 API and necessary flags
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint SetThreadExecutionState(uint esFlags);
    public const uint ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000;
    public const uint ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

My favorite way of doing this without any additional software is to use the built in **Mobility Center** of Windows. It can be quickly accessed using the [Windows key]+[X] shortcut of Windows 8:

[image: Opening Mobility Center]

Then simply switch **Presentation Mode** to on.

[image: Turning presentation mode on]

As long as this particular mode is on, the computer will not turn off the screen and will not go to sleep.

*Only downside: Mobility Center is only available on mobile computers, as far as I know.*

Answer (score 0):

You could write a batch file to do this. Something really easy. There is a command in Windows 7 that allows you to adjust the Power Management features. Your batch file could be setup to prompt you for different features and based on how you answer the settings would be changed. [Here's a start](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700230.aspx). I had used this command to automatically disable the sleep feature in Windows 7 and it worked well.

Comment: Patrick S. post made me remember [this](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/). a great little application called caffeine. Execute and it will keep your computer running until you close it!

Answer (score 0):

Try [NoDoz](https://github.com/refactorsaurusrex/NoDoz). It prevents sleep while running, just like insomnia. But with NoDoz you can also pass in a timeout parameter like `-t 6h13m` to have the program automatically end after an arbitrary amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft PowerToys has an "Awake" util that can inhibit sleepmode for a number of hours.

[Awake screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fmCp.png)

Check the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/awake

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1195265)